# org mode babel use contents of block as file in another block

Tags: org-babel

I'm trying to define some data in json file and use the file name in another bloc as command parameter. Something like that:

```
The data:
#+BEGIN_SRC json
{
  "Foo": "Bar"
}
#+END_SRC

... and the script
#+BEGIN_SRC json
do_something_with_json $the_data
#+END_SRC
```

Is it possible?

Comment: I find another way to solve this issue in - https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/65104/how-to-pass-org-babel-code-block-as-variable-to-another-code-block

Answer (score 1):

Read [(org) var](http://orgmode.org/manual/var.html) for the capabilities. As far as I know, you can't reference a src block without run it, but you can reference a literal example, for example, you have put your json data into an EXAMPLE block

```
#+NAME: json_data
#+BEGIN_EXAMPLE
{
  "method": "+",
  "params": [1, 2, 3]
}
#+END_EXAMPLE
```

then you can reference the json data via its NAME

```
#+BEGIN_SRC sh :var x=json_data
echo $x | jq .method
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
: +
```

here is another use

```
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :var x=json_data
(let-alist (let ((json-array-type 'list))
             (json-read-from-string x))
  (apply (intern .method) .params))
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
: 6
```