# How to pass org-babel code block as variable to another code block?

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

I would like to pass the code from code block `test_python` to `script`. I do not want `test_python` to be evaluated, but simply to have the source code inserted into `script` when I evaluate script. The goal is to have a more generic extended version of `script` that will do some useful stuff to setup the environment and run the contents of `test_python` such that it can be run on different machines. I'd like to eventually hide the `script` block in a `#+INCLUDE`ed org mode file, then just be able to have the `test_python` block and a `#+CALL` to `script` in the primary org mode.

A minimal example where I am trying to do this is:

```
#+NAME: test_python
#+BEGIN_SRC ipython :results none :exports none
  import numpy as np

  x0 = np.arange(-1, 1, 1/10.)
  x1 = np.arange(-1, 1, 1/10.)
  x0, x1 = np.meshgrid(x0, x1)
  y_truth = x0**2 - x1**2 + x1 - 1

  print('inside python')
#+END_SRC

#+NAME: script
#+HEADER: :var python_code=""
#+BEGIN_SRC bash :results output
  #!/bin/bash

  result=$(python <<EOF
  $python_code
  EOF
  )
  echo $python_code
  echo $result
  echo "done test"
#+END_SRC

#+NAME: script_generator
#+CALL: script[:var python_code=test_python]
```

Adding one more thing: I am actually tangling `script` to write to file. I just removed that for the sake of the example.

--- Edit

I had left out some of this to try to get to a minimal example, but it seems that will make the question more clear. Ultimately I want this to look like the following.

any org file I'm currently working in:

```
* Some cool org stuff
:PROPERTIES:
:OUT_SCRIPT: /ssh:otherMachine:~/scripts/test_python.sh
:END:

#+INCLUDE: ~/org/script_utils.org

#+NAME: test_python
#+BEGIN_SRC ipython :results none :exports none
  import numpy as np

  x0 = np.arange(-1, 1, 1/10.)
  x1 = np.arange(-1, 1, 1/10.)
  x0, x1 = np.meshgrid(x0, x1)
  y_truth = x0**2 - x1**2 + x1 - 1

  print('inside python')
#+END_SRC

#+NAME: script_generator
#+CALL: script[:var python_code=test_python,script_path=OUT_SCRIPT]
```

and

script_utils.org:

```
#+NAME: script
#+HEADER: :var python_code="", script_path=""
#+BEGIN_SRC bash :results output :tangle script_path
  #!/bin/bash

  result=$(python <<EOF
  $python_code
  EOF
  )
  echo $python_code
  echo $result
  echo "done test"
#+END_SRC
```

Comment: What about Noweb reference syntax (https://orgmode.org/manual/Noweb-Reference-Syntax.html)? This looks like a typical use case here.

Comment: @Philopolis your comment would be a good answer for this question, if you added a short explanation

Answer (score 5):

The [Noweb reference syntax](https://orgmode.org/manual/Noweb-Reference-Syntax.html) may help in such cases. Using this syntax, the body of a given code block can be executed inside the body of another code block. As a summary of the Org manual page:

1. You have to `NAME` the first code block
2. Add its `<<NAME>>` in a second code block, which will have `:noweb yes` as a header argument. Then, `<<NAME>>` will be expanded/interpreted as the contents of the first code block.

I give an example below, adapted from your own example:

```
#+NAME: test_python
#+BEGIN_SRC python :results none :exports none
import numpy as np

x0 = np.arange(-1, 1, 1/10.)
x1 = np.arange(-1, 1, 1/10.)
x0, x1 = np.meshgrid(x0, x1)
y_truth = x0**2 - x1**2 + x1 - 1

print('inside python')
#+END_SRC

#+NAME: script
#+BEGIN_SRC bash :results output :noweb yes
#!/bin/bash
result=$(python <<EOF
<<test_python>>
EOF
)
echo $result
echo "done test"
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS: script
: inside python
: done test
```

Comment: This is almost it, but what is missing is being able to do this:

```
#+NAME: script_generator
#+CALL: script[:var python_code=test_python]
```

Comment: The instruction `#+CALL: script` (without additional argument) should work.

Comment: I expanded my question. I explicitly want to pass the name of the block/noweb-ref to the other block.